# How do I secure a shower curtain rod?

Tags: bathroom, shower

In my bathroom I have one of those spring-loaded shower curtain rods that you twist to get tight. When any real weight is on it, it moves, and if it moves enough, the whole thing comes crashing down.

Where do I find a non-spring loaded rod and fixtures to secure it to the walls? This seems like a silly question to me, but I've never seen anything but the spring loaded rods in the big box stores. Am I just missing them? Or is this somehow a specialty item?

Comment: When you say 'big box stores', are you talking about places like Home Depot and Lowes?  Because I've actually seen a larger variety in the home decor section at Target.  (and they have the curved ones that Mike Powell mentioned).  Try looking in places that sell home decor, rather than hardware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can buy brackets like this one that attach to the walls.  You still use a spring loaded rod, but the ends go into the brackets and the brackets keep the rod from falling.

Typically the brackets are attached to the wall with standard drywall anchors.

[image: shower rod bracket]

Comment: That's exactly correct, its the easiest way to do this, in fact I've never seen a home with the shower rod held up any other way. Those twist ones never work.

Comment: Thanks! Are these sold at Home Depot and Lowes? Would they be in the bathroom section?

Comment: @Scott - I believe so, yes

Answer (score 4):

Or, for $40 or so, you could get a fancy [curved shower rod](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017ZKZ70).  It also screws into the wall with drywall or tile anchors, and in my opinion is a big improvement over a standard straight rod.  It looks nice on the outside and makes the shower a lot roomier on the inside.