# How do I design a quasi tamperproof shower curtain rod mounting point for eldery with Alzheimers?

Tags: bathroom, shower, mounting, design, brackets

## Question

I am seeking another solution to keep a shower curtain rod from falling easily. There were other posts that mentioned drilling and mounting.

**I would prefer, if possible, something that is secure, but can be removed wihtout having to take out a screwdriver or drill.**

## Desired Project Outcome

I am trying to come up with a solution to prevent this or to greatly reduce the possibility of the rod falling again.
I do not want them to feel guilty for calling and asking for help, but I also do not want to be called for everything.(trying to preserve independence for both all parties as possible).

I want to **prevent**, not **treat** a problem.

## Solutions I looked at

[How do I mount a shower curtain rod to tile?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6672/59323)

[Eric Petroelje's solution to How do I secure a shower curtain rod?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4451/59323)
[image: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4451/59323]
It is a good one, but do not know how difficult or easy it is to take the bar down. I need it somewhat accessible since I have to clean the shower.
(For curtains, a solution may to just get easy detachable rings) 
**Overall, I think this is the best solution.**

## My proposed solution

I am curious to see if there is some sort of slot, where the mount will be drilled to the wall, but the shower road will lock into place ( very secure) and can be unlocked for easy removal.

The best example of a slot or bracket, I can give you is camera mount bracket[image: camera mount bracket]

## Dive Ladder Bracket

[Dive Ladder Bracket Lock](http://www.armstrongnautical.com/ladders.htm)
[image: Dive ladder slot mechanics]

> Inspiration from this
>
> ## Dive Ladder On Back of Boat [image: Dive Ladder Non Fish Platform]

## Background to help you understand who you are designing solution for

I have a grandfather who worked as a diesel mechanic for 30 years. He is now in his late 80s and has dementia.(elderly, confused)

I mention the mechanic part, because he loves to tinker, pull, grab, squeeze and touch things because he did so while working for many years to solve problems on the job.

Unfortunately, lately he does this to everything and it is getting worse.

A few hours ago he channeled his inner Nadia Comaneci (Famous Olympic Gymnast) ,  pulled down the bar. (I am trying to make the best of the situation, add humor to it so my grandmother keeps her sanity because it can be stressful living with someone who is ,literally, slowing losing their mind.)
My grandmother, also 89, cannot put the rod back into place because she is too short.

## Pictures of Shower Curtain Rod

> Example of possible bar it could be (I do not know what type of bar they have, could not find packaging) :

[Moen TR1000 44" - 72" Adjustable Tension Shower Curtain Rod](https://www.build.com/moen-tr1000/s731805)
[image: 44" - 72" Adjustable Tension Shower Curtain Rod]

## Shower rod they currently have

## 1

[image: Shower_Curtain_with_Rod]

## 2

[image: Shower_Rod_against_wall]

## 3

[image: Overview_of_shower]

Comment: Your requirement *that the rod be removable for cleaning* is your problem. I have never heard of that. No house I've ever lived in has had that.  Give it up.  Everything becomes easy.

Comment: My parents too.  A shower rod **should not come down. Period. Ever.**  The rod linked, like any compression rod, is a trailer-park grade *piece of (what you have too much of already)*.  Not least, it falling on them or draping the curtain over them is already a health risk. The curtain clips must fail first for safety. Look at the grab, that's how secure a rod should be.

Answer (score 1):

I think a standard shower rod will work. The brackets screw into the wall, and then the rod rests on some tabs that keep it from moving. Covers slide into place to hide the innards of the bracket.

This is about as secure as you can get it, without making the rod difficult to remove. You can pull back the bracket covers and remove the rod easily.

Tension rods are notorious for loosening up over time and falling, and would not be a good choice for somebody who likes to grab and pull on them.

I think your concern about the rod needing to be easily removable may be a bit overblown. The curtain can just be pulled aside when you need to clean the shower, unless you have some specialized equipment you need to get in there

Answer (score 1):

I want to add one safety point to the good answers here.  Do not underestimate how strong Alzheimers patients can be, especially when they are agitated.  /My MIL bent steel (yes, really) when she had a bad episode.  Therefore, you may want to factor not just strength but ease of repair into your equation.  If you drill into the tile and your gramps pulls out the bracket, that is a hard fix.

You also want to think about whether the loose rod could be used as a weapon.  I'm sorry to say this but Alzheimers patients can go a little wild sometimes, and you don't want gramps wielding a 4ft steel bar over your nana.  It may be better to deliberately have something flimsier and spend your time adapting it so your nana can reattach it herself.  Like a hollow plastic pipe (cpvc say) resting in a U-shaped bracket with a t-joint near the end and a 9" pipe acting as a little handle of sorts so she can push up and hook it back on.

Don't mean to be negative about the elderly, but I lived through this and sometimes you have to do weird DIY solutions to keep your loved ones safe.

Comment: I appreciate the perspective. You bring up great points about the anger.